# Cannot connect to hive using beeline, user root cannot impersonate anonymous

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I'm trying to connect to hive using beeline `!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000` and I'm being asked for a username and password

---

`Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000'
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: 
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000:`

---

As I don't know what username or password I'm supposed to type in I'm leaving it empty which causes the error: `Error: Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: root is not allowed to impersonate anonymous (state=,code=0)`
 
My setup is a single node hadoop cluster in ubuntu.
I can confirm that the services are up and running, both hadoop and hiveserver2

The question is , what are these username and password I'm being asked, where can I find them or set them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is a testing environment I set up in an ubuntu virtual machine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should provide a valid `username` and `password` that has privileges to access the HDFS and Hive Services (`user` running HiveServer2). For your setup, the `user` in which Hadoop and Hive are installed would be the superuser.

These credentials will be used by `beeline` to initiate a connection with HiveServer2.

And, add these properties in `core-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.username.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.username.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
```

Restart services after adding these properties.

Then run `beeline` with the specified user name `username` as below:

```sh
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 -u username
```

ref: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2#SettingUpHiveServer2-Impersonation

Alternatively, you can also set the parameter `hive.server2.enable.doAs` to `false` to disable user impersonation.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I have tried what you suggested but unfortunately it did not solve my problem, I still get the same error.

Comment: What username did you pass in `beeline`? It should be same as the username in the property.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this. In which property?

Comment: In core-site.xml file, `hadoop.proxyuser.<username>.hosts` the `<username>` here must be same as the one used in `beeline`,

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts worked.

Comment: @franklinsijo THANK YOU. The username in the parameter name is the thing I needed. 2000 other pages and no one but you mentioned that.

Answer (score 11):

In hive-site.xml need to set the parameter hive.server2.enable.doAs to
false

```
<property>
<name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
<value>FALSE</value>
<description>
Setting this property to true will have HiveServer2 execute
Hive operations as the user making the calls to it.
</description>
</property>
```

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201602.mbox/%3C54b7754ceb8370b7250bba929369763f@cloudtechnologypartners.co.uk%3E

Comment: Thanks this worked for me with hive 2.1.0 and hadoop 2.9.2. Just remember to restart all hadoop services and thrift server.